# Trigger view event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a Backbone View with simple events:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "change #id": "idChanged"
    },
    idChanged: function () {}
    initialize: function () {
        /* construct HTML */

        $("#id").trigger("change");
    }
});
```

However this does not fire the `idChanged` event.  When I change `#id` with the  browser it *does* fire.  How can I trigger the Backbone View event?

Comment: are you saying the event is fired when using the browser, but from the `initialize` method it is not firing

Comment: if the `#id` element is part of the view, it won't exist on initialization, only when the view is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of things in your code.

1 I don't think you defined your events correctly.

It should be a hash, or a function that returns a hash, like so:

```
events: {
    "change #id": "idChanged"
}
```

2 a few typos like "function" and missing comma

then, to make the events work, the defined #id element must be inside the view's `el`. If the element is outside of the view, it's not gonna work.

also, you cannot trigger that in initialize, because before that function is executed, the view is not fully initialized yet. :)

here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3KmzQ/

Comment: Thanks, this is helping.  The `function ()` stuff was just a typo on my part; I've corrected it.  I need to be able to trigger the event within the view though; is there something that gets called after `initialize` that I can use?

Comment: since you will need to render the view anyways....you can do it in render: http://jsfiddle.net/3KmzQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `events` hash will be bound to the view when it gets rendered, which happens *after* the `initialize` code gets run. Try calling the desired callback directly:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    events: function () {
        "change #id": "idChanged"
    },
    idChanged: function () {}
    initialize: function () {
        /* construct HTML */

        this.idChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but now the event data is not in the `idChanged` method which I need (specifically `e.target` for the `#id` element and possibly other stuff)

Answer (score 0):

You used "extend".
Same code should apply to Backbone.view.Object( {....} )
Specify the object that you would like to fire events at.

```
Backbone.View.Ojbect(
  {
    events: function () {

    "change #id": "idChanged"
    },

idChanged: funciton () {}

initialize: function () {
    /* construct HTML */
    $("#id").trigger("change");
}
}
);
```

That is, try not to extend.